# Does rfeControl function in caret create stratified folds?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I want to do feature selection of my random forrest model following the approach of [rfe](http://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html) of the caret package. As my data set contains only about 100 labeled samples and as it is highly unbalanced (which reflects real life balance), I need/want to do stratified cross validation. However, I did not find any documentation about the `rfeControl` function regarding stratified cross validation.

Does anybody know if the `rfeControl` function does create stratified folds if I use

```
ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
               method = "cv",
               verbose = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `method ="cv"`, `rfe()` should use `createFolds()` to create your folds, and these will be balanced based on your output variable. 
You can see `?createFolds` for details on how this is implemented.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation of createFolds notes **For createFolds and createMultiFolds, the number of groups is set dynamically
based on the sample size and k. For smaller samples sizes, these two functions may not do stratified splitting and, at most, will split the data into quartiles.** So I am not quite sure when and how this dynamic adjustment is done, but I will try `method = "cv"` and look at the results.

Comment: Yes, it will depend on your data. You can also use the argument `index` in `rfeControl` to pass your own indices (possibly created with `createFolds`).